# Как удалить свой принятый ответ?

Tags: обсуждение, удаление-ответов, принятые-ответы

Допустим я разместил ответ и он принят автором вопроса. Через некоторое время появляется альтернативный ответ.

Я считаю, что новый ответ лучше, чем мой. Однако удалить свой собственный ответ я не могу, так как он принят и система не дает мне его удалить. Предусмотрен ли какой-то механизм в этом случае?

Как лучше поступить?

Comment: [По всей видимости](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31585419/clojure-alphanumeric-sorting/31585978#31585978), **никак**.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Можно написать комментарий к своему ответу и/или к вопросу с прямой просьбой к автору принять другой ответ. Тут же дать ссылку на более удачный ответ и обосновать свой выбор.

Во-первых, автор может откликнуться. Во-вторых, другие участники увидят ваше мнение.

**UPD**

Автор ответа оценивает свой ответ по своим субъективным критериям качества, а автор вопроса - по полезности для себя. Могут быть детали, по которым оказался полезен именно этот ответ, как бы ни были хороши все остальные.

Поэтому здесь важна последовательность в действиях. Раз просили оценивать ответ по полезности и раз автор вопроса это уже сделал, то ответ должен оставаться на виду, пока именно автор вопроса не передумает.

Уравновешивающий момент вижу в том, что остальные участники могут заплюсовать другой ответ, и тот разместится сразу после принятого.

Comment: Спасибо за рекомендации, так и поступил. А интересно, что произойдет, если будет заминусован принятый ответ, я даже не смогу его удалить под "давлением общества"?

Comment: Если не удастся узнать у более опытных коллег, то можно обсудить эксперимент. Продумать, что проверяем и как моделируем ситуацию. И спросить мнение сообщества  и модераторов насчёт такого эксперимента. Вот [есть опыт](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/3015/208926).

Comment: @cheops Да, может получиться, что у вас не будет права удалить свой вопрос или ответ, который насобирал минусов, причём такое может получиться даже при оценке –100, когда количество снимаемой репутации реально ощутимо.

Comment: @Discord, не получится, ага. Я только что попробовал удалить мой принятый ответ с -8 — не даёт.